# How do I make an input selector form element trigger another input selector to appear based on the option choosen

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the following for a restaurant menu:

I have a input selector in a form  that shows 2 options soup and salad.  When I choose soup nothing should happen but when I choose salad I want to add below another input selector drop down box the shows dressing choices.

Is there a way to do an if statement that says if salad is selected add the new field into the form?

I would like to be able to do this with jquery only and without using AJAX and PHP but I can if I need to.

Comment: Post a [mcve] showing us what you've tried and where you got stuck please

Answer (score -1):

You will select the option then with .select() function after it.